# unable to replace global variable which is two hops away

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

i was trying create an insert function for a binary search tree. but i am unable to replace the global variable ,which is null at first, but am able to replace non null global variable which is two hops away (i.e via the parameter). the following code show what the problem is.

```
struct tree{
    int a;
    tree* right;
    tree* left;
};
tree* root=NULL;
void insert(tree* in, int b){
        if(in){
            if(in->a<b)
                    insert(in->right,b);
            else if(in->a>b)
                    insert(in->left,b);
            else
                cout<<"the value is already in the tree."<<endl;
        }else{
            tree* temp = new tree;
            temp->a=b;
            temp->right=NULL;
            temp->left=NULL;
            in=temp;// this does not change the root(global variable) value
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even expect that in=temp changes the global variable somehow? You're assigning to a local variable (a function parameter).

Comment: replace the raw pointers with `unique_ptr<>` and life becomes a little bit more simpler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change a pointer from a function, you need to pass a double pointer to that function.

```
struct tree{
    int a;
    tree* right;
    tree* left;
};
tree* root=NULL;
void insert(tree** pIn, int b){
        tree* in = *pIn;

        if(in){
            if(in->a<b)
                    insert(&(in->right),b);
            else if(in->a>b)
                    insert(&(in->left),b);
            else
                cout<<"the value is already in the tree."<<endl;
        }else{
            tree* temp = new tree;
            temp->a=b;
            temp->right=NULL;
            temp->left=NULL;
            *pIn=temp;
        }
}
```

Although semantically correct, this is not the best design ever.

Or, as @NathanOliver suggests, you could use a reference instead of the second pointer.

```
struct tree{
    int a;
    tree* right;
    tree* left;
};
tree* root=NULL;
void insert(tree*& in, int b){
        if(in){
            if(in->a<b)
                    insert(in->right,b);
            else if(in->a>b)
                    insert(in->left,b);
            else
                cout<<"the value is already in the tree."<<endl;
        }else{
            tree* temp = new tree;
            temp->a=b;
            temp->right=NULL;
            temp->left=NULL;
            in=temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: Or you can pass it by reference like `tree*& pIn`

Comment: i prefer the reference one. since i don't have to cast the point every time i call it. what other `best` design do you guys suggest for adding a node to BST?